# Почему sys.platform возвращает 32 на Windows 64-bit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ос

Процессор компьютера x64, OS Windows 10 Тоже 64-bit,
но команда  `sys.platform`  показывает 32.

Что означает это цифра и нужно ли переустанавливать python ?

Comment: 32 это число, а не цифра.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Документация к sys.platform](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform) обращает внимание, что для Windows значение этой строки всегда будет `'win32'`.

Чтобы проверить систему на разрядность, следует использовать [sys.maxsize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize), например, так:

```
def isSys64bit():
    return sys.maxsize == 2**63-1
```

Answer (score 5):

Для получения правильной информации используйте не стандартный модуль `sys`, а стандартный модуль `platform` - например так:

```
In[1]: import platform
In[2]: platform.machine()
```

> ```
> Out[2]: 'AMD64'
> ```

```
In[3]: platform.uname()
```

> ```
> Out[3]: uname_result(system='Windows', node='Work7', release='7', version='6.1.7601', 
>            machine='AMD64', processor='Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel')
> ```